# How to copy Key Value Elements from one Hash Table to the other HT

Tags: java

I am trying to copy first 5 key value pair from Hash Table 1 to Hash Table 2
and Then next 6 to 10th Key value pair from Hash Table 1 to Hash Table 3.

I am not able to get this going,, can any one has any hint please share it with me

Comment: sorry but I don't really see how that can cause difficulties. Can you show have you tried so far and explained why it doesn't work instead ?

Comment: Hashtable entries are generally unordered. Can you explain what you mean by "first 5 key value pair"? First in what order?

Comment: @Matt, Before I copy, eveyr time i add the entries into the Hash table,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
Hashtable h1 = new Hashtable();
Hashtable h2 = new Hashtable();
Set s = h.keySet();
int i = 0;
for (Object key : s) {
    if ( i++ < 3) {
        h1.put(key, h.get(key));
    } else {
        h2.put(key, h.get(key));
    }
}
```

Add generics etc. as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that a `Hashtable` does not maintain the order in which elements are inserted, so the first 5 can be whatever.

If you want the insertion order to be preserved, use a `LinkedHashMap` (perhaps wrapping it in a `Collections.synchronizedMap()` if you want it to be thread-safe).

Besides, there's also a nice interface called `NavigableMap`, implemented by `TreeMap`, which offers methods like `subMap()`, but you need to know from which key to which key (instead of using indices). And this will also hold your entries sorted by the key.

If you can rely only on indices, aside from using a `LinkedHashMap`, I would suggest you go for a generic solution like the following:

```
<K, V> Collection<Map<K, V>> splitMap(Map<K, V> map, int count) {
    if (count <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("zero or negative count");
    }
    List<Map<K, V>> list = new ArrayList<Map<K, V>>();
    Iterator<Entry<K, V>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        list.add(subMap(entries, count));
    }
    return list;
}

<K, V> Map<K, V> subMap(Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator, int count) {
    Map<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        Entry<K, V> entry = iterator.next();
        map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Then just call splitMap(yourMap, 5) in order to get the collection (actually a list) of maps containing 5 entries each (or less for the last one if there are not enough entries in the initial map).